# Execute function as soon as a value occurs a certain number in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, count

I would like to call a function as soon as a value in a column of a DataFrame occurs a certain number (e. g. 3x).

Label_Test (size: 268, 4)

most of the values are 1 but some values are 3. So I want to call a function as soon as the value 3 occurs 3 times in a row.

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    if Label_Test[i][:] == 3:
        FunctionX()
```

I tried sth like this...

Thank you!

Comment: Is this pandas or numpy?

Comment: Can you share example of your input?

Comment: Also, what happens if 3 comes 4 times in a row? Will you call the function twice? (one for each time the count crosses the threshold)

Comment: It is pandas. 
The function should be called as soon as 3 comes 3 times in a row. If it comes 4 times or more it should also call this function. But if in the meantime a value is != 3, it should be counted from the beginning again.

Comment: @PeterStöger Can you please check whether the answer you accepted is who you meant to? You can only accept one, and the other answer does not come close to solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup -

```
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1])
s

0     1
1     1
2     3
3     3
4     1
5     3
6     3
7     3    # 1
8     1
9     1
10    3
11    3
12    3    # 2
13    1
dtype: int64
```

Based on my understanding of the question, you to determine when 3 occurs 3 (or more) times. You can do this with pandas.

1. Find consecutive groups
2. Label the groups using a neat `groupby` trick
3. Find all those rows whose modulo 2 `cumcount` value is 2, and the corresponding value in `s` at that index is 3

```
s.groupby(s.eq(3).ne(s.eq(3).shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().mod(3).eq(2) & s.eq(3)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12     True
13    False
dtype: bool
```

You can determine how many times, and at what point of time (by observing the index) this condition occurs so you can call your function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the logic in your functionX

```
def functionX(x):
    if x==3:
        return 50
    else:
        return x

original_data=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,3,1,1,2],'col2':[1,3,1,1,3,2]})
modified_data=original_data.applymap(functionX)
```

original_data:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     1     3
2     3     1
3     1     1
4     1     3
5     2     2
```

modified_data:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     1    50
2    50     1
3     1     1
4     1    50
5     2     2
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my answer solves the problem pre-edit. looking at the current question I cannot figure out why my answer has been accepted